# Audi A3 2003 fsi drive problems

Tags: transmission, audi

looking for some advice. My Audi A3 2003 fsi, 70,000kms was driving the other day and all of a sudden I lost off drive, it’s as if the gearbox went into neutral and I had to pull over. I turned off the engine, back on again and it would drive about 10m before happening again. Got it towed back Home and left it for a few days and then tried to drive again, I got about 800m from my house and the issue happened again. There is a slight whining sound coming from engine 
Has anyone got a diagnosis or theory on what could be the issue, and wether it’s going to cost me a lot of money? 
Any help would be great!